# Como usar uma credencial na url quando o nome do usuário trata-se de um email? é preciso escapar?

Tags: http, url

Para você fazer conexões via SSH, geralmente usa-se as credenciais diretamente na url não ser necessário definir o usuário e senha toda hora.

Exemplo:

```
 ssh://login:senha@site.com/repos/repositorio.git
```

É exatamente o que estou fazendo para utilizar o `Bower` para gerenciar as dependências de CSS e javascript, porém eu tenho que utilizar o usuário e senha, pois o repositório está no Bitbucket.

Porém, recentemente criamos um usuário que, para se autenticar, é necessário passar o email e a senha.

Mas pelo que eu saiba, o caractere `@` faz parte da separação entre `host` e `credenciais do usuário`.

Sendo assim, se eu precisar conectar um usuário que contenha o `username` como o e-emai, como eu poderia fazer?

Exemplo, preciso autenticar esse usuário:

```
 usuário: desenvolvimento@meusite
 senha: 123456
```